# Can't display the last number after the for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

How do I display the last number after the `for` loop?

This program is used to calculate the Euler method

- for `xO` I enter 0
- for `yO` I enter 1
- for `send` I enter 1

I attempt to obtain the last value of `y` when `x=1.0`, but now I can't get it done.

```
    float num,xO,yO,xend,x,y,delx,func,exact,diff;
    char next ='y';
    while( next =='y') {
    cout << "Please enter the method of choice;press 1 for Euler's Method,"<< endl;
    cout << "press 2 for Heun's Method:";
    cout <<setiosflags(ios::showpoint);
    cin  >> num;
    if ( num==1 ) {
        cout <<"Solution for the equation dy/dx = f(x) by Euler's Method"<< endl;
        cout <<"Enter the initial condition xO :";
        cin  >> xO;
        cout <<"Enter the initial condition yO :";
        cin  >> yO;
        cout <<"Enter the final value of x :";
        cin  >> xend;
        cout <<"Enter the step size delta_x :";
        cin  >> delx;
        y=yO;
        for ( x=xO; x <=1.00000016; x+=delx  ) {
            cout<<setw(10)<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setprecision(2)<<x<<setw(10)<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setprecision(6)<<y<<endl;
            func=4*x*y;
            func=sqrt(func);
            y=y+((delx)*(func));*//the last y is 2.54052
        }
        cout<<"\nThe solution y10 at x=1 is "<<y<<endl;
}
```

The number I want to display is 2.54052 but now it is 2.85930. How should I correct this?

Comment: Numbers of type float always have some imprecision and are not suitable in for loops.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Don't keep adding, you get less and less accurate. Multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Use integers instead of float numbers in the condition section of your **for** loop.

For example, instead of "float x <=1.00000016", use "int x <= 100000016" so that no precision is lost.

Then, divide the values within the curly braces of the **for** loop by 1e8 and explicitly convert them into type float.

```
float func = static_cast<float>(4 * x * y) / 100000000;
```